# Redirect users to the page before after login with component

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, joomla3.4

In Joomla 3.5.1, I want to redirect users to the page they were before logging in.

If they login from mod_login, no problem, since the module is pending from the top menu, they just stay at that page.

The problem happens when the users login from the component: they are always redirected to the profile page.

In the menu item `index.php?option=com_users&view=login` there's an option to redirect users after login.

But how do I tell: `"Get them back to the page they were before"`?

Certain components are appending something like:

```
?return=L2YlQzMlQjNydW0tcGVyZ3VudGFzLWUtcmVzcG9zdGFzL2NvbnZlcnNhdGlvbi9yZWFkLmh0bWw/aWQ9MjU=
```

To the URL, requesting a redirect to a specific page.

But they alwawys go back to the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

return="XXXX"

The code appended to the return parameter is the base64_encoded value of the url which we need to redirect after login.

Check out below link for more details.
https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login%3F